# Problem expanding $f(x)=x\ln(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})-\sqrt{1+x^2}$ into a power series

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

So here is my solving process:
$$
\begin{split}
f(x)=x\ln(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})-\sqrt{1+x^2}&\Rightarrow f'(x)=\ln(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})\\
&\Rightarrow f''(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}
\end{split}
$$ and from here I apply the generalized binomial formula $(x+y)^r=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\tbinom{r}{k} x^{r-k}y^k$ with $r=-\frac{1}{2}$:
$$
f''(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}x^{2n}
$$and integrate $f''(x)$ back to get the expansion series of the original function
$$
f'(x)=x+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n(2n-1)!!}{(2n+1)(2n)!!}x^{2n+1}
$$
$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{2}x^2+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n(2n-1)!!}{(2n+1)(2n+2)!!}x^{2n+2}
$$
But the correct answer should be $f(x)=-1+\frac{1}{2}x^2+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n(2n-1)!!}{(2n+1)(2n+2)!!}x^{2n+2}$. I don't know where the constant term -1 comes from(but it makes sense since $f(0)=-1$), is there any problem in my solution? Or should I always check for constants possibly missing in my series expansion?

Comment: when you integrate you should always keep track of the $+C$. You were actually quite lucky in your calculation, because $f'(0)=0$, so your series for $f'(x)$ is right. Unfortunately, you weren't completely lucky, because as you can see your $f(x)$ is off by a constant.

Comment: Why not using the fact that $f'(x)=\sinh ^{-1}(x)$ ? This would be simpler.

Comment: @peek-a-boo is right - integrating twice, you have two constants to find.

Comment: +1 For good MathJax and for clearly demonstrating your efforts. MathJax tip: try using the command `\ln` instead of writing just `ln`. Note the difference between `$\ln x$` and `$ln x$`, which produce $\ln x$ and $ln x$ respectively.

Comment: [connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2021806)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting different answers when integrating using different techniques](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3453558/getting-different-answers-when-integrating-using-different-techniques)

Comment: It could help to notice that $\;\log(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})=\text{arsinh}\,x=\;$ the inverse hyperbolic sine...and in this line, $\;\sqrt{1+x^2}=\cosh(\text{arsinh}\,x)\;$ ...

Comment: @peek-a-boo thx I should've noticed that, it seems all too normal now

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I'm not so familiar with hyperbolic functions and their expansions.